# Catch2 cmake function 'catch_discover_tests()' not work in bulid time

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

I use Catch2 for Unittest. I want run test after build. 
So I use 'cath_discover_test' function in Catch. 
but in build time, not print out anything about test.
 like below:

```
> cmake --build .
blah ~
blah ~
PostBuildEvent:
  setlocal
  "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -D TEST_TARGET=foo -D TEST_EXECUTABLE=C:/Users/MyName/workspace/someproject/build/
  Debug/foo.exe -D TEST_EXECUTOR= -D TEST_WORKING_DIR=C:/Users/MyName/workspace/someproject/build -D TEST_SPEC= -D TEST_EXT
  RA_ARGS= -D TEST_PROPERTIES= -D TEST_PREFIX= -D TEST_SUFFIX= -D TEST_LIST=foo_TESTS -D CTEST_FILE=C:/Users/MyName/workspace/a
  someproject/build/foo_tests-b858cb2.cmake -P "C:/Program Files (x86)/Catch2/lib/cmake/Catch2/CatchAddTests.cmake"
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  :cmEnd
  endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
  :cmErrorLevel
  exit /b %1
  :cmDone
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
  :VCEnd
blah ~
blah ~
end
```

This is **test.cmake** file source code:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(foo ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(foo Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(foo)
```

but, I execute test through ctest likes below, test work.

```
>ctest
Test project C:/Users/MyNames/workspace/someproject/build
    Start 1: some class test
1/1 Test #1: some class test .............***Failed    0.02 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.04 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - some class test (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

How Can I run test and show output of test result after build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake does not expect you to run tests at the same time as build. You can imagine a cross compiler situation where the target architecture is not the same as your host build machine, in that situation it would make no sense to run tests while building.

I you want to run the built tests as part of CMake build look at `add_custom_command` to run a `POST_BUILD` command.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/contrib/Catch.cmake) of  catch_discover_tests function. in line of 123, It use add_custom_command & POST_BUILD command.